# Dark matter as an emergent phenomenon

Tags: dark-matter, modified-gravity, emergent-properties

Dark matter is invoked as a solution to anomalies in galactic rotation curves, galaxy motions in clusters, and gravitational lensing (please mention other evidence for dark matter that is relevant to this question).

In physics, the phenomenon at different scales and levels of complexity can't fully be described by the fundamental laws governing a single item in the system. This is why elementary particle physics $\neq$ condensed matter. This point is well summarized by Novel Laureate Philip Anderson in "More is Different",

> The
>   behavior of large and complex aggregates of elementary particles, it turns
>   out, is not to be understood in terms
>   of a simple extrapolation of the properties of a few particles. Instead, at
>   each level of complexity entirely new
>   properties appear, and the understanding of the new behaviors requires research which I think is as fundamental
>   in its nature as any other.

In light of this, have people looked at explaining the above dark matter anomalies in this way? I'm wondering if perhaps a large ensemble of gravitating bodies could behave in a manner that isn't explained solely by their individual interactions. Is this idea just MOND? Does it even make sense to apply this concept to this problem?

Comment: Maybe useful: https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.02269

Comment: Yes, that does sound like MOND.